# jQuery grid with multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datagrid, multi-select

I'm looking for  grid with multiselect, based on jQuery.
Purpose is time frames selector, so user get grid with

```
 day1 |  day2 |  day3 
00:00 | 00:00 | 00:00  
00:30 | 00:30 | 00:30  
01:00 | 01:00 | 01:00  
01:30 | 01:30 | 01:30  
02:00 | 02:00 | 02:00  
03:30 | 02:30 | 02:30
```

etc. User should be able to select multiple time frames for multiple days (so I need selection for cells, not rows as in usual datagrids). Also Shift+mouse / Ctrl+mouse selection merging needed. Could anyone suggest existing module with such functionality?

Comment: Have you considered using the checkbox styling options of jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Comment: Thank you for your tip. It is look nice, but I can't select multiple cells at once (like file selection in explorer, while mouse button is pressed). Anyway if I couldn't find exactly what I need I will play around UI.

Also "selectable" looks reasonable.